# Pretty print data in tkinter Label

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label, tabulate

I have following sample data

```
data=[(1,'JohnCena','Peter',24,74),
      (2,'James','Peter',24,70),
      (3,'Cena','Peter',14,64),
      (14,'John','Mars',34,174)]
```

I want to print it on python gui in a beutiful tabular way on tkinter output window. I am using [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) package to print.
Here is my function

```
def display_date():
    disp=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['id','first name','last name','age','marks'])
    newwin = Toplevel(right_frame)
    newwin.geometry('500x400')
    Label_data=Label(newwin,text=tabulate(disp, headers='keys',tablefmt='github',showindex=False))
    Label_data.place(x=20,y=50)
```

You can see the output is not symmetric. I want a beautiful symmetric tabular output. How can I do that

Here is the output
[image]

Comment: Try use a monospaced font. `Label(...,font='Consolas')`

Comment: I think you need some monospace font (meaning all letters have the same width) to align the columns correctly that `tabulate` produces. For example with the parameter `font='Roboto Mono'` inside the label.

Comment: Alternate design proposal: create one Entry object for each cell and arrange them in a grid. When you have a GUI, you don't need to use text to position your data.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: `tabulate` output, displayed in a `tk.Label`, without to distort the data.

---

As pointed out in the comments this can be done using a `monospaced font`.
You have to use the following `Label` options,

```
justify=tk.LEFT
anchor='nw'
```

to justify the table `left`, and stick it to top left position.

---

**Reference:**

- [The Tkinter Label Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm)
- [tabulate](https://pyhdust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabulate.html)
- [Print tabular formated text into a tk.Text widget, not aligned as its supposed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59346200/7414759)

---

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tabulate import tabulate

data = [('id', 'first name', 'last name', 'age', 'marks'),
        (1, 'JohnCena', 'Peter', 24, 74),
        (2, 'James', 'Peter', 24, 70),
        (3, 'Cena', 'Peter', 14, 64),
        (14, 'John', 'Mars', 34, 174)
        ]


class TabulateLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, data, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, 
                         font=('Consolas', 10), 
                         justify=tk.LEFT, anchor='nw', **kwargs)

        text = tabulate(data, headers='firstrow', tablefmt='github', showindex=False)
        self.configure(text=text)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        TabulateLabel(self, data=data, bg='white').grid(sticky='ew')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```